# Setting up LVM partitions on an existing machine without LVM preinstalled

Tags: partition, lvm, aws

I have a few machines running debian, already up and using their filesystem, the `/` partition is mounted directly on the partition.

With minimum damage to the fs and minimum downtime, how can I set it up so that the `/` partition will be LVM?

NOTE: no physical access to the machines - all of them are on AWS.

EDIT: Actually making the `/` partition LVM is not my main goal. Releasing only some of the hard-drive so I can get my `/tmp` and other world writable directories on LVM is sufficient as well.

Comment: I would leave root alone, and add partitions with LVM for other subdirectories.

Comment: For in place conversion to LVM, there is a tool https://github.com/g2p/blocks#readme and a German howto do it manually https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Howto/LVM_nachtr%C3%A4glich_einrichten/ which I'm too lazy to translate. All in place conversions always come with a certain amount of risk and you still have to fix bootloaders etc. which usually requires some sort of rescue system.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I'd leave / and /boot out of LVM. The snapshots and resizing are nice but grub and lvm don't always place nice together (they're supposed to, of course) but I do remember a bug in grub a few years ago that prevented booting from an LVM volume if there was an existing snapshot of the root filesystem. While this is most certainly fixed, the actual issue is that when there are problems, it is almost entirely opaque to you and difficult to troubleshoot. I lean towards simplicity so I prefer to use LVM for the other volumes. YMMV.

Comment: Though I one time I did use LVM for /, now I do not. As @Tim says, it is not worth it. My partitions are /boot: 256 MB, /: 768 MB; rest is on LVM, with separate partition for /var, /usr, /home and swap.

Comment: Wouldn't mind leaving `/` alone and just add LVM on the side, only that `/` is taking all the space. I need a reasonable way to take out some space from that partition. I don't think I can do this while it is mounted, so my question is, if at all possible, what is the least damaging (down time and risk of loss of data) way to do so.